# redirect via htaccess where IP is not && remove index.php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, expressionengine

I usually use this htaccess file to remove index.php from my URLs in ExpressionEngine

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

AcceptPathInfo On

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks

# Looks for files and directories that do not exist
# and provide the segments to the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^/index.php
RewriteCond $1 !.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

While that works great, before we move this site into production, we're directing all traffic to the given url to another via this htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.anotherdomain.com/ [R=301,NC]
```

My own ip address is replacing the localhost call so that I can access the site.

Basically what I'm looking for is a combination of these 2 that will remove index.php from my URLs for me but still redirect everyone else.

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: Not sure what you need, but you say you need to combine both - so why you don't just add the `REMOTE_ADDR` condition to the above rewrite? Am I missing somethig?

Comment: That's the thing, I tried that. I added my {REMOTE_ADDR} rule after my usual rules but even with my IP address added, I always get redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this works great:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If your IP address matches any of these - then dont re-write
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.anothersite.com/ [R=302,L]


# do not rewrite links to the assets and theme files
RewriteCond $1 !^(assets|themes|images)

# do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt etc
RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt|crossdomain\.xml)

# but rewrite everything else
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```